# String can't be coerced into Float for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, floating-point

I'm getting this error, **"String can't be coerced into Float"** when this line is executed:

**mechanic_dictionary[:cost] = "%.2f" % labor_item.hourly_cost * inv_item.hours_worked**

but when I modify the line to this:

**mechanic_dictionary[:cost] = "%.2f" % 1.0 * 1.0**

Then the program displays the value correctly which is **1.00**

Does anyone know why the error occurs when i use the **labor_items** and **inv_items** objects?

Note- I am using ruby on rails

Comment: Need more details - what are the values and types for `labor_item.hourly_cost` and `inv_item.hours_worked`?  You might just need a `.to_f` on the end of those, but it's impossible to tell.

Comment: the objects are floats.  I tried putting the .to_f after each of them, but i still get the error

Comment: Maybe you could show us an example of the exact value of `labor_item.hourly_cost` and `inv_item.hours_worked`?

Comment: When I run the debugger this is what the objects show
(rdb:1) inv_item.hours_worked
#<BigDecimal:5af93a8,'0.2E1',9(18)>
(rdb:1) labor_item.hourly_cost
#<BigDecimal:5af9240,'0.24E2',9(18)>
(rdb:1)

Comment: when i add the .to_f after the object then this is what I get
(rdb:1) inv_item.hours_worked.to_f
2.0
(rdb:1) labor_item.hourly_cost.to_f
24.0
(rdb:1)

Comment: `"%.2f" % ( BigDecimal.new("0.2E1") * BigDecimal.new("0.24E2") )` works for me. What about your `mechanic_dictionary`? Is it an ordinary hash?

Comment: yes.  I declared it like this

mechanic_dictionary = Hash.new

Answer (score 3):

Put parentheses around the product:

```
"%.2f" % (labor_item.hourly_cost.to_f * inv_item.hours_worked.to_f)
```

Recall that the ruby operators `*` `/` and `%` are of equal precedence and have left-to-right associativity.

The reason this works

```
"%.2f" % 1.0 * 1.0
```

is because `"1.00" * 1.0 == "1.00"`. It is evaluating `"%.2f" % 1.0` first.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I did try putting the parenthesis around the the objects, but it still gives me the same error

Comment: @Eric Answer updated. Have you tried using the parentheses, AND placing a `.to_f` on BOTH `hourly_cost` and `hours_worked`?

Comment: yes I did try that but still getting the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

```
"%.2f" % ( labor_item.hourly_cost * inv_item.hours_worked )
```